# por qué cuando ploteo en matplotlib (con este código) sale incompleto?

Tags: python, matplotlib

estoy buscando plotear una sísmica (en gris) con matplotlib y encima de la sísmica una correlación (que seria de varios colores), la correlación hace alusión a los horizontes rastreados previamente, horizon_number es el número de horizontes que se quiere ver (también es opción visualizar todos con "all"), view es para diferenciar entre inline y xline (tipos de lineas en la sísmica), line_number es el número de línea que se va a mostrar y selem es un parámetro para la dilation, el código es sencillo pero la gráfica sale incompleta y no sé por qué. También estoy abierta a opciones si a alguien se le ocurre algo con xarray.  Acepto sugerencias y recomendaciones por favor. Adjunto código e imagen.

```
def ShowHorizon (seismic_data, horizons, horizon_number, view, line_number, selem):
    correlated_cube= np.zeros(seismic_data['data'].shape, dtype=np.float32)
    if horizon_number == 'all':
        num=0
        correlated_cube= np.zeros(seismic_data['data'].shape, dtype=np.float32)
        for i in range (0, len(horizons)):
            reflector=horizons[i]
            num=num+1
            for p in reflector:
                x=p[0]
                y=p[1]
                z=p[2]
                correlated_cube[x,y,z]=num
    else:
        reflector=horizons[horizon_number]
        for p in reflector:
                x=p[0]
                y=p[1]
                z=p[2]
                correlated_cube[x,y,z]=correlated_cube[x,y,z]+1 #+1 FOR Å FÅ EN IDE OM HITRATE

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    if view == 'inline':
        A=correlated_cube[:,line_number,:]
        I=seismic_data.isel(iline=line_number)
        variables1 = I.data_vars
        arrays1 = [ I[i].values.flatten() for i in variables1 ] 
        arrays1 = [i for j in arrays1 for i in j  ]
        array1 = np.array(arrays1).reshape(-1,1)
        B= array1.copy()
    if view == 'crossline':
        A=correlated_cube[:,:,line_number]
        X=seismic_data.isel(xline=line_number)
        variables2 = X.data_vars
        arrays2 = [ X[i].values.flatten() for i in variables2 ] 
        arrays2 = [i for j in arrays2 for i in j  ]
        array2 = np.array(arrays2).reshape(-1,1)
        B= array2.copy()
        
        
    A = dilation(A, selem)
    masked_data = np.ma.masked_where(A < 1, A)
    plt.imshow(B, 'gray', aspect='auto')
    plt.imshow(masked_data, 'jet', alpha=0.9, aspect='auto')
    
    if horizon_number == 'all':
        cbar = plt.colorbar(ax=None)
        cbar.set_label('Horizon number')
    else:
        cbar = plt.colorbar(ax=None)
        cbar.set_label('Autotracking accuracy (Hit rate)', rotation=270)
        cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([]) #no labels on colorbar
    
    plt.xlabel('intersecting lines')
    plt.title('Autotracked horizons superimposed onto seismic')
    plt.ylabel('Samples')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
    return
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

me parece que el tema radica en estas que se estan combinando dos estilos diferentes de graficar. Esto es

Primero se esta usando el estilo `POO` con la linea
`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

Y luego se esta usando el esilo de `pyplot` con las lineas

```
plt.imshow(B, 'gray', aspect='auto')`
plt.imshow(masked_data, 'jet', alpha=0.9, aspect='auto')
```

Es por esto que grafica aparece vacia. Pues primero se genero el objecto `ax` pero no se le estan asignado valores. Simultanemante, se genero otro objeto `plt` pero no se indica donde mostrarse.

Me parece que se busca graficar un mapa de calor por lo que con las siguientes lineas deberia de aparecer:

```
# Usando estilo POO
fig, ax = plt.subplots() # Notar que esta en plural
ax.pcolormesh(B, 'gray', aspect='auto')
ax.pcolormesh(masked_data, 'jet', alpha=0.9, aspect='auto')
```

o alternativamente

```
# Usando estilo pyplot
plt.subplot() # Notar que esta en singular
plt.imshow(B, 'gray', aspect='auto')
plt.imshow(masked_data, 'jet', alpha=0.9, aspect='auto')
```

En caso de querer explorar mas sobre la guia de graficado, referirse a la guia oficial:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/quick_start.html#coding-styles

En cuanto a ejemplos de mapa de calor

- Usando poo:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-listed-colormaps

- Usando pyplot

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_adjust.html#subplots-spacings-and-margins

Espero sea de ayuda.