# armar un grafico en matplotlib correctamente

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

estoy trabajando a modo experimental en el analisis de un DF.

mi problema es: Tengo una tabla que armé concatenando 2 columnas, 'valor_neto' y 'Cilidrada'.
necesito armas un grafico que me demuestre si en función de aumentar la cilindrada, aumenta el valor neto.

comparto imagen del df.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo:

```
data = data.groupby(by='Cilindrada')['Valor_Neto'].max().reset_index()
data.sort_values(by='Valor_Neto', ascending=False, ignore_index=True, inplace=True)


f,ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))




plt.barh(data['Cilindrada'],data['Valor_Neto'])
plt.show
```

quedo atento y muchas gracias.

Comment: El problema es que a `plt.show`  le faltan parentesis. deberia ser `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Justo como lo comenta el compañero @SembeiNorimaki, hace falta llamar la funcion `plt.show()` pues sin los parentesis, solo se crea el objecto pero no se ejecuta.

Adicional a esto, quisiera agregar que la forma actual del codigo mezcla dos estilos diferentes de como graficar con matplotlib. Si bien, este caso parece graficar y no dar problemas. Pero cuando sea casos mas complejos (multiples graficos, graficos complejos o miltuples figuras), esta mezcla de estilos puede llevar a confusion de que se esta modificado o a comportamiento inesperado. (Un ejemplo de esto: [por qué cuando ploteo en matplotlib (con este código) sale incompleto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/590789/329827))

Para revisar a detalle la mezcla de estilos:

```
# Metodo explicito (o POO) pues define f,ax
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

# Metodo implicito (al usar pyplot):
plt.barh(data['Cilindrada'],data['Valor_Neto'])
plt.show()
```

Ahora, graficando pero en diferentes estilos:

- Explicito (POO): En general, recomendado para graficos complejos. Se llama explicito porque explicitamente se detalla que objecto se grafica y/o modifica. En este caso, le estamos diciendo que en el objecto `fig` agregue el grafico con `ax.barh`. Esto ultimo de `ax` es lo que nos permitira agregar mas graficos y determinar por cuadrante el grafico que se quiera plotear o modificar.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.barh(data['Cilindrada'],data['Valor_Neto'])
```

- Implicito (pyplot): En general, bueno para graficos sencillos. Se llama implicito porque implicitamente se modifican o grafican los objectos. Si bien, tambien se le pueden agregar multiples figuras y graficos, llega un momento donde se complica su modificacion.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.barh(data['Cilindrada'],data['Valor_Neto'])
```

En caso de querer profundizar al respecto, la guia oficial de matplotlib de estilos es:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/quick_start.html#coding-styles

Y para saber mas a detalle las ventajas y desventajas de cada estilo:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#api-interfaces

Espero sea de ayuda.